# Spring data MongoDB GeoSpatial Distance

Tags: geospatial, spring-data-mongodb

I trying to find the distances along with the locations by using Spring Data Mongo GeoSpatial.

Following this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.geo-near

```
GeoResults<VenueWithDisField> = template.query(Venue.class) 
.as(VenueWithDisField.class)                            
.near(NearQuery.near(new GeoJsonPoint(-73.99, 40.73), KILOMETERS))
.all();
```

I tried

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RestaurantWithDisField {
   private Restaurant restaurant;
   private Number dis;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "restaurants")
public class Restaurant {
   @Id
   private String id;
   private String name;
   @GeoSpatialIndexed(name = "location", type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
   private GeoJsonPoint location;
}

public GeoResults<RestaurantWithDisField> findRestaurantsNear(GeoJsonPoint point, Distance distance) {
    final NearQuery nearQuery = NearQuery.near(point)
            .maxDistance(distance)
            .spherical(true);
    return mongoTemplate.query(Restaurant.class)
            .as(RestaurantWithDisField.class)
            .near(nearQuery)
            .all();
}
```

But in the result I am getting the below. If I don't set the target type and just collect the domain type I get all the other values but the distance.

```
Restaurant - RestaurantWithDisField(restaurant=null, dis=0.12914248082237584
Restaurant - RestaurantWithDisField(restaurant=null, dis=0.19842138954997746)
Restaurant - RestaurantWithDisField(restaurant=null, dis=0.20019522190348576)
```

Can someone please help me why I am unable to fetch the domain type value or how should I?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The mapping fails to resolve `restaurant` in `RestaurantWithDisField` because the values within the result `Document` do not match the target entities properties.

You might want to use inheritance instead of composition here and let `RestaurantWithDisField` extend `Restaurant`, provide your own converter or just use `Restaurant` and rely on `GeoResults` holding a list of `GeoResult` that already include the `Distance` along with the actual mapped domain type - pretty much the same, that you've be modelling with `RestaurantWithDisField`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Mongo repository can generate the right query for you if you name it correctly and put the data into your domain POJO. I was able to find examples [here - blocking](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/7b33f56e334e265f6fd153ed52b2d59e75ce8524/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/query/MongoQueryMethodUnitTests.java#L252) or [here - reactive](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/7b33f56e334e265f6fd153ed52b2d59e75ce8524/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/query/ReactiveMongoQueryMethodUnitTests.java#L201).

```
interface RestaurantRepository extends MongoRepository<Restaurant, String> {
    Collection<GeoResult<Restaurant>> findByName(String name, Point location);
}
```

From what I see, the (Reactive)MongoTemplate uses a `GeoNearResultDocumentCallback` to wrap the `restaurant` in a `GeoResult`. You may want to take a look there.